# Unknown Connection String.Name: 'core' error

Tags: configuration

I was setting up one of the sites in my local and I am facing the `Unknown Connection String. Name: 'core'` error when I try to browse the site. Have imported the databases into my local SQL management studio.

[image]

Here is the connectionstring file :

```
 <add name="core" connectionString="Data Source=xxx;User ID=sa;password=welcome1@;Database=sitecore-core-2022-3-15"/>
        <add name="master" connectionString="Data Source=xxx;User ID=sa;password=welcome1@;Database=sitecore-master"/>
        <add name="web" connectionString="Data Source=xxx;User ID=sa;password=welcome1@;Database=sitecore-master"/>
        <add name="custom" connectionString="Data Source=xxx;User ID=sa;password=welcome1@;Database=sitecore-custom"/>
        <add name="web2" connectionString="Data Source=xxx;User ID=sa;password=welcome1@;Database=sitecore-master"/>
```

The log is not generating any error related to the above issue it only says as below
[image]

Can anyone please suggest how do I need to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Can you check this file `\App_Config\Sitecore\CMS.Core\Sitecore.CoreDatabase.config` and compare with vanilla instance or any old solution you have on your local?

Comment: Try validating the XML of the entire config file. Also try wrapping your password in single quotes in case it has a reserved character. Also try restoring the vanilla Web.config to see if that helps.

Comment: @Sumit Bhatia i don't see that config file in my local neither in the vanilla instance

Comment: @Vinaya Please specify your Sitecore version

Comment: @Sumit Bhatia sitecore version is 8.2 revision 170614

Comment: I face same issue, in my case database name was not correct, could you please verify?

Comment: @RishirajShekawat have specified the correct db name but still am seeing this issue

Comment: @Vinaya as you mentioned that you have imported the database. So am thinking you are working with some external database. Did you try with the OOTB databases that came with the Sitecore Vanilla instance?